# What is an alpine start?

Tags: mountaineering, terminology

Sometimes climbers/mountaineers will say that they are getting an alpine start.

What does this mean and why would they want to do this?

Comment: For cavers: anything before about 5pm ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alpine start is when **one starts a climb really early in the morning** (well before sunrise). Usually the goal is to make it to the top and back down before the conditions deteriorate.

Getting too late of a start increases a number of risks including,

- Thunderstorms
- Rockfall
- Weakened snow bridges
- Crampons balling up

Other times its worth getting an alpine start just to see the sunrise from the top of a mountain.

Comment: An alpine start is also often done to beat the crowds and maximize hours of daylight during climbing.

Comment: @shimizu I usually do it to minimize hours of daylight on tour: Every more hour increases temperature and radiation from sun, thus softens snow.

Comment: To be clear - Most often you do an Alpine Start its because it is the the end of the day that matters.

Comment: @shimizu Plenty crowded climbing up a high mountain in the Alps at 04:00.