# How to get up for an alpine start without an alarm?

Tags: mountaineering, alpine, time

Sometimes, one needs to get up for an [alpine start](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17004/what-is-an-alpine-start) i.e. really, really early, and yet not have a functioning alarm. Cell phones have a tendency to lose the correct time when shut off and then turned back on in an area with no service and watches can break or run out of batteries.

Are there any tips for still getting up really early **without an alarm**?

Comment: I always have difficulty getting any quality sleep at all the night before an alpine start but that's me... BTW, alpine start implies alpinism, and I wouldn't start up the mountains without an altimeter. In my case a watch wich has an alarm.

Comment: I have never had this problem with a cell phone.  Is this a problem that modern smartphones have?

Comment: @gerrit I have had it happen with multiple cell phones, it happens when there is absolutely no service.

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh Odd.  I've frequently hiked in areas far away from any service but never had this happen.  When getting up is very important I additionally use the alarm clock on my Garmin GPS-receiver, though.  That one always has coverage as I've yet to sleep in caves or slot canyons :)

Comment: My cheap Timex is more then 5 years old, nearly unbreakable, and has sounded an alarm or two daily for the entire time.

Comment: You normally climb with a partner, the chances of two watches and two phone simultaneously getting broken /going flat or not alarming while you are both asleep, and neither of you getting woken up by the event, are pretty slim - missing the alpine start will be the least of your worries.

Comment: @mattnz Unless your me, in which case mountaineering solo is pretty normal. I did 4 alpine starts in a 5 days for 6 peaks with the methods I outlined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some things that will help in getting up early without an alarm.

- Drink **more water than normal** before bed , this ensures that you won't sleep all of the way through the night.
- Try to sleep so that the rising moon/early twilight will **shine on you earlier** (don't sleep on the west side of a big rock)
- Once, up **don't go back to sleep** even if that means starting slightly earlier than you had planned.
- Get to bed **early**.
- If you do this enough times in a short time span, it is possible to approximate the time before sunrise by the position of Venus in the sky.
- Remember that it is important to get up early, and that you can sleep later in the day.